# Powershell Delete empty nodes from xml file

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to delete empty nodes from xml file.

ex:

```
     <Keys>
      <Key Name="Topic" />
      <Key Name="Topic" />
      <Key Name="Topic" />
      <Key Name="Keyword" />
      <Key Name="Keyword" />
      <Key Name="Keyword" />
      <Key Name="Keyword">Musk deer</Key>
      <Key Name="Keyword">Hunting</Key>
      <Key Name="Keyword">Trapping</Key>
      <Key Name="Keyword">Mythology</Key>
      <Key Name="Topic">Traditional narrative</Key>
    </Keys>
```

The idea is remove this nodes:

```
      <Key Name="Topic" />
      <Key Name="Topic" />
      <Key Name="Topic" />
      <Key Name="Keyword" />
      <Key Name="Keyword" />
      <Key Name="Keyword" />
```

Any suggestion, to help me on this?

Best

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML Object in PowerShell like this:

```
$FileContent = New-Object -Typename XML
# Load file
$FileContent.Load("C:\Temp\in.xml")
$Nodes = $FileContent.SelectNodes("//Key")
# For each node
foreach ($Node in $Nodes) {
    if ($Node.InnerXml -ne "") {
        $Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Node)
    }
}
# Save file in UTF-8
$ConfigFileEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
$ConfigFileWriter = New-Object System.XML.XMLTextWriter("C:\Temp\out.xml", $ConfigFileEncoding)
$ConfigFileWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$FileContent.Save($ConfigFileWriter)
$ConfigFileWriter.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Damien.

Comment: How do you delete it if the innerxml is empty?

Comment: Juste change the condition into "if ($Node.InnerXml **-eq** "") {"